# How to make image change every couple of defined hours based on time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this but it does not show any image. If you could explain how to make it work so that the image comes out at the specified times that would be great. I will be switching out the images so that each time period has a different image. Thank you so much!

```
setInterval(function () {
    var hours = new Date().getHours();
     $("#hours").html((hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours);

if (hours >= 5  && hours < 7) {
    if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("night-sky-background.jpg")==-1){
              $("body").css("background-image", "images/night-sky-background.jpg");
          }
}
else if (hours >= 7 && hours < 8) {
    if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("night-sky-background.jpg")==-1){
              $("body").css("background-image", "images/night-sky-background.jpg");
          }
}
else if (hours >=8 && hours < 9) {
    if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("night-sky-background.jpg")==-1){
              $("body").css("background-image", "images/night-sky-background.jpg");
          }
}
else if (hours >=9 && hours < 11) {
    if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("night-sky-background.jpg")==-1){
              $("body").css("background-image", "images/night-sky-background.jpg");
          }
}
else if (hours >=11 && hours < 14) {
    if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("day-sky-background.jpg")==-1){
             $("body").css("background-image", "images/day-sky-background.jpg");
          }
}
else if (hours >=14 && hours < 18) {
    if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("day-sky-background.jpg")==-1){
             $("body").css("background-image", "images/day-sky-background.jpg");
          }
}
else if (hours >=18 && hours < 22) {
    if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("day-sky-background.jpg")==-1){
             $("body").css("background-image", "images/day-sky-background.jpg");
          }
}
else if (hours >=22 && hours < 24) {
    if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("day-sky-background.jpg")==-1){
             $("body").css("background-image", "images/day-sky-background.jpg");
          }
}
else {
    if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("day-sky-background.jpg")==-1){
             $("body").css("background-image", "images/day-sky-background.jpg");
          }
}
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`background-image` should be `url(images/day-sky-background.jpg)`.

(You're missing the `url( ... )`)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) in conjuction with jQuery to attain your objective, no need to do if-else branching.

**Edit:**

```
function Background(){
    var imgs = [
            "images/day-sky-background1.jpg",
            "images/day-sky-background2.jpg",
            "images/day-sky-background3.jpg",
            "images/day-sky-background4.jpg",
            "images/day-sky-background5.jpg",
            "images/day-sky-background6.jpg",
            "images/day-sky-background7.jpg",
            "images/day-sky-background8.jpg",
            "images/day-sky-background9.jpg"
        ],
        len = imgs.length,
        idx = -1;

    setInterval(function(){

       var hours = new Date().getHours();
       $("#hours").html((hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours);
       idx = (idx+1)%len;
       if (hours >= 5  && hours < 7) {
           idx = 1;
       }else if (hours >= 7 && hours < 8) {
           idx = 2;
       }else if (hours >=8 && hours < 9) {
           idx = 3;
       }else if (hours >=9 && hours < 11) {
           idx = 4;
       }else if (hours >=11 && hours < 14) {
           idx = 5;
       }else if (hours >=14 && hours < 18) {
           idx = 6;
       }else if (hours >=18 && hours < 22) {
           idx = 7;
       }

       $("body").css("background", "#000 url("+imgs[idx]+")");
    }, 60*60*1000); //call every hour
}
```

Comment: While your code does contain the `url()` part that will fix the code, this does alter functionality rather drastically. You're just cycling through the images every hour, always starting with the first image, regardless of time of day, and assuming that the user will want a uniform distribution of images. The change will occur on the hours after the `setInterval` has been called, not when the actual hours change, and the way its written, it can't be increased to the second-precision OP is using, because the change of images is contingent upon the interval.

Comment: In a typical website, this will practically always be showing whatever's at `imgs[0]`

Comment: @DavidHedlund Thanks for the suggestion answer has been updated accordingly.